# How control goes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

Why the output is:
Hello world
Hello Avishek

Why not:
Hello Avishek
Hello World
Because at first function fun() is executing and then console.log("Hello world")

```
function fun(name){
    console.log("Hello "+name);
}

var s=setTimeout(fun,2000,"Avishek");
console.log("Hello world");
```

Comment: Because you are not waiting for the timeout to finish before you log "Hello world"

Comment: Learn javascript and call stack in javascript.

Comment: `fun` is not executing first.

Comment: your question is very confusing

Comment: You can see a visual demonstration of how that code executes on [latentflip.com/loupe](http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=ZnVuY3Rpb24gZnVuKG5hbWUpewogICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkhlbGxvICIrbmFtZSk7Cn0KCnZhciBzPXNldFRpbWVvdXQoZnVuLDIwMDAsIkF2aXNoZWsiKTsKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkhlbGxvIHdvcmxkIik7!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D)

Comment: Have a look at what [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) does.

Answer (score 1):

[`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) executes the defined function (`func` in you case) after the defined timeout (2000ms).
Therefore `console.log("Hello world")` will be executed before.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout is non blocking meaning it won't stop execution, so the order is

- create timeout
- log: `Hello World`
- 2 seconds later run `fun`
- log: `Hello Avishek`